# how to remove properties via mapped type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, mapped-types

Here is the code

```
class A {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    visible = false;
    render() {

    }
}

type RemoveProperties<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Function ? T[P] : never//;
};


var a = new A() as RemoveProperties<A>
a.visible // never
a.render() // ok!
```

I want to remove " visible / x / y " properties via RemoveProperties ,but I can only replace it with never

Answer (score 70):

### TS 4.1

You can use [`as` clauses](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) in [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to filter out properties in one go:

```
type Methods<T> = { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends Function ? P : never]: T[P] };
type A_Methods = Methods<A>;  // { render: () => void; }
```

> When the type specified in an `as` clause resolves to `never`, no property is generated for that key. Thus, an `as` clause can be used as a filter [.]

Further info:  [Announcing TypeScript 4.1 - Key Remapping in Mapped Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#key-remapping-mapped-types)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oA8BcUB2ArgLYBGEATmhiLoaRVegG4CWAziyQDYS4kD2-HgEM8jKOQh4AJhQAUASlxN+LaSgC+KFKEhQAshGAALftLYAeACoA+BMigBtAApQWeKAGsIIfgDMoKyhhNkCXAF0oCExgKXMoADECPABjYBZ+DwB+KFdaCCYKcNwrCKgNAG4dcGgYAH1DEzNQxEbTcwsYGwr0AHpeh0kZClxFBDsVNR6NIA)

Comment: This pattern started [causing issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51141) for me, in TS 4.7+ above. Any idea why?

Answer (score 58):

You can use the same trick as the [`Omit`](http://ideasintosoftware.com/typescript-advanced-tricks/) type uses:

```
// We take the keys of P and if T[P] is a Function we type P as P (the string literal type for the key), otherwise we type it as never. 
// Then we index by keyof T, never will be removed from the union of types, leaving just the property keys that were not typed as never
type JustMethodKeys<T> = ({[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Function ? P : never })[keyof T];  
type JustMethods<T> = Pick<T, JustMethodKeys<T>>;
```

Comment: I have another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420657/how-to-remove-properties-and-promisify-method-via-mapped-type-in-typescript    , thanks for your help