# Add parameters to every member of parent interface in child interface

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to expand every method of parent interface in child interface?

```
interface IFoo {
    methodOne(a: any)
    methodTwo(a: any)
}

interface IBar extends IFoo {
   //make IBar have all methods of Ifoo, but make it take additionlal arguments
   //as in methodOne(a: any, b: any, c: any)
   // and methodTwo(a: any, b: any, c: any)
}
```

is there a way to achieve this, without repeating all code from IFoo?

Comment: A solution that does this without redefining all function is possible in 2.8 unsing conditional types, see this answer for inspiration, I will add an answer later if no one else does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420657/how-to-remove-properties-and-promisify-method-via-mapped-type-in-typescript/49421381#49421381

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using mapped types and conditional types in typescript 2.8 (unreleased at the time of writing, should be released in March, currently in RC, you can get it via `npm install -g typescript@rc`)

```
// Helper
type IsValidArg<T> = T extends object ? keyof T extends never ? false : true : true;

// Works for 3 parameters you can add more as needed, see link below for info
type AddParameters<T> =
    T extends (a: infer A, b: infer B, c: infer C) => infer R ? (
        IsValidArg<C> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, addedA: any, addedB: any) => R :
        IsValidArg<B> extends true ? (a: A, b: B, addedA: any, addedB: any) => R :
        IsValidArg<A> extends true ? (a: A, addedA: any, addedB: any) => R :
        (addedA: any, addedB: any) => Promise<R>
    ) : never;

type InterfaceWithExtraParameters<T> = {
    [P in keyof T ] : AddParameters<T[P]>
}

interface IFoo {
    methodOne(a: string): string
    methodTwo(a: number): number
}
type IBar = InterfaceWithExtraParameters<IFoo>;
// Equivalent to :
// type IBar = {
//     methodOne: (a: string, addedA: any, addedB: any) => string;
//     methodTwo: (a: number, addedA: any, addedB: any) => number;
// }


// Can be imelmented by a class
class BarImpl implements IBar {

    methodOne(a: string, addedA: any, addedB: any): string{
        return a;
    }
    methodTwo(a: number, addedA: any, addedB: any): number {
        return a;
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a lot of ceremony to get this done, you might be better off for simple single use cases to just redefine the methods, but it is up to you which route you choose.

To extend `AddParameters` for more parameters see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420657/how-to-remove-properties-and-promisify-method-via-mapped-type-in-typescript/49421381#49421381)

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: the last link "answer" goes to your user profile page

Comment: @MariuszPawelski 10x for the catch, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend an interface and add optional parameters:

```
interface IBar extends IFoo {
    methodOne(a: any, b?: any, c?: any);
}
```

The ? makes the parameters optional. But you have to define them with additional parameters.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I know of. I thought that there might be a way to shorten the code, since all methods of child interface have the same parameters added.