# Function Argument Type Inference through Generics behaves weirdly

Tags: typescript

Have a look at this simple example code:

```ts
interface EventEmitter<ListenersT>
{
    on<EventT extends keyof ListenersT>(event: EventT, listener: ListenersT[EventT]): this;
}

interface MyEvents
{
    foo(x: number): void;
    bar(): void;
    moo(a: string, b: Date): void;
}

interface MyEmitter extends EventEmitter<MyEvents>
{}

const my: MyEmitter = <any> {};

my.on('foo', (x) => x / 4); // Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type.
my.on('bar', () => 42);
my.on('moo', (a, b) => a + ': ' + b.getFullYear());
```

I am wondering why in the `my.on('foo', ...)` call the compiler fails to infer the type of `x`, while it works fine for both arguments in the `my.on('moo', ...)` call.

You can go and test this [on the Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20EventEmitter%3CListenersT%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09on%3CEventT%20extends%20keyof%20ListenersT%3E(event%3A%20EventT%2C%20listener%3A%20ListenersT%5BEventT%5D)%3A%20this%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyEvents%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09foo(x%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%09bar()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%09moo(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20Date)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyEmitter%20extends%20EventEmitter%3CMyEvents%3E%0D%0A%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20my%3A%20MyEmitter%20%3D%20%3Cany%3E%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Amy.on('foo'%2C%20(x)%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2F%204)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Parameter%20'x'%20implicitly%20has%20an%20'any'%20type.%0D%0Amy.on('bar'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%2042)%3B%0D%0Amy.on('moo'%2C%20(a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20a%20%2B%20'%3A%20'%20%2B%20b.getFullYear())%3B%0D%0A). You can enable the `noImplicitAny` flag by pressing the *Options* button to get the warning I put in the comment or just hover over the `x` argument in the code window to see that it failed to infer the `number` type.

Bonus: This gets even weirder, if I add another argument to `foo()`. In that case it also fails to infer the types for `moo`'s arguments.

### Edit 1

It appears it's only able to infer the types for the function in `MyEvents` with the most arguments and only if it's the only one with that amount of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript has trouble inferring the arguments to callbacks when the type of the callback depends on another parameter, I have seen this in several SO questions (I can search for some if you want).

The solution is to put the problem in a different way, that is to make the `on` function have several overloads. The trick is to do this without having to restate all signatures from the interface.

Your requirements are very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369299/can-i-reuse-the-parameter-definition-of-a-function-in-typescript/50375712#50375712) answer, and you will find a more detailed explanation there, but modified to your needs the code would look something like this:

```
interface EventEmitter<ListenersT>
{
    on : OnAll<ListenersT, this>
}

type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

type OnSignatures<T, TReturn> = { [P in keyof T]: (event: P, listener: T[P]) => TReturn }
type OnAll<T, TReturn> = UnionToIntersection<OnSignatures<T, TReturn>[keyof T]>

interface MyEvents
{
    foo(x: number): void;
    bar(): void;
    moo(a: string, b: Date): void;
}

interface MyEmitter extends EventEmitter<MyEvents>
{
    // on is now equivalent to an on with these overloads
    //on(event: 'foo', listener: (x: number) => void): this;
    //on(event: 'bar', listener: () => void): this;
    //on(event: 'moo', listener: (a: string, b: Date)=> void): this;
}

const my: MyEmitter = <any> {};

my.on('foo', (x) => x / 4); //  x is number 
my.on('bar', () => 42);
my.on('moo', (a, b) => a + ': ' + b.getFullYear());
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20EventEmitter%3CListenersT%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09on%20%3A%20OnAll%3CListenersT%2C%20this%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20UnionToIntersection%3CU%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%09(U%20extends%20any%20%3F%20(k%3A%20U)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3A%20never)%20extends%20((k%3A%20infer%20I)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%3F%20I%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20OnSignatures%3CT%2C%20TReturn%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20(event%3A%20P%2C%20listener%3A%20T%5BP%5D)%20%3D%3E%20TReturn%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20OnAll%3CT%2C%20TReturn%3E%20%3D%20UnionToIntersection%3COnSignatures%3CT%2C%20TReturn%3E%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyEvents%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09foo(x%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%09bar()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%09moo(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20Date)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyEmitter%20extends%20EventEmitter%3CMyEvents%3E%0D%0A%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20my%3A%20MyEmitter%20%3D%20%3Cany%3E%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Amy.on('foo'%2C%20(x)%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2F%204)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%20x%20is%20number%20%0D%0Amy.on('bar'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%2042)%3B%0D%0Amy.on('moo'%2C%20(a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20a%20%2B%20'%3A%20'%20%2B%20b.getFullYear())%3B%0D%0A)