# Extensible, strongly typed Event Emitter Interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have been using a strongly typed event emitter interface in Typescript for a while, but now I need it to support subclasses that add own events to it. At some point Typescript fails to be aware of the base class events.

Here is the code in a condensed version ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20UnionToIntersection%3CU%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(U%20extends%20any%20%3F%20(k%3A%20U)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3A%20never)%20extends%20((k%3A%20infer%20I)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%3F%20I%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AddParameters%3CListenersT%2C%20EventT%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ListenersT%20extends%20(...args%3A%20infer%20ArgsT)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20(event%3A%20EventT%2C%20...args%3A%20ArgsT)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cboolean%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20EmitSignatures%3CListenersT%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%5BEventT%20in%20keyof%20ListenersT%5D%3A%20AddParameters%3CListenersT%5BEventT%5D%2C%20EventT%3E%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20EmitAll%3CListenersT%3E%20%3D%20UnionToIntersection%3CEmitSignatures%3CListenersT%3E%5Bkeyof%20ListenersT%5D%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20OnSignatures%3CListenersT%2C%20ReturnT%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%5BEventT%20in%20keyof%20ListenersT%5D%3A%20(event%3A%20EventT%2C%20listener%3A%20ListenersT%5BEventT%5D)%20%3D%3E%20ReturnT%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20OnAll%3CListenersT%2C%20ReturnT%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20UnionToIntersection%3COnSignatures%3CListenersT%2C%20ReturnT%3E%5Bkeyof%20ListenersT%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20EventEmitter%3CListenersT%3E%20%3D%20EmitterInterface%3CListenersT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20EmitterInterface%3CListenersT%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20emit%3A%20EmitAll%3CListenersT%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20on%3A%20OnAll%3CListenersT%2C%20this%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20VehicleEvents%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20accelerate(acceleration%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20brake(deceleration%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20BusEvents%20extends%20VehicleEvents%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doorStateChange(front%3A%20boolean%2C%20middle%3A%20boolean%2C%20rear%3A%20boolean)%3A%20void%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Vehicle%3CE%20extends%20VehicleEvents%3E%20extends%20EventEmitter%3CE%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onSig%3A%20OnSignatures%3CE%2C%20this%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onSigs%3A%20OnSignatures%3CE%2C%20this%3E%5Bkeyof%20E%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Vehicle%3CE%20extends%20VehicleEvents%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20this.on('brake'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20this.flashBrakeLights())%3B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20supposed%20to%20work%3F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20flashBrakeLights()%3A%20void%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20hitTheGas(strength%3A%20number)%3A%20void%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20this.emit('accelerate'%2C%20strength%20*%2042)%3B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20supposed%20to%20work%3F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20test()%3A%20void%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.onSig.accelerate%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.onSig.brake%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.onSigs('accelerate'%2C%20(a)%20%3D%3E%20undefined)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%20I%20don't%20understand%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.onSigs('brake'%2C%20(d)%20%3D%3E%20undefined)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%20I%20don't%20understand%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.onSigs('foo'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20undefined)%3B%20%2F%2F%20supposed%20to%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Bus%20extends%20EventEmitter%3CBusEvents%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Bus%20extends%20Vehicle%3CBusEvents%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20doorState%3A%20%5Bboolean%2C%20boolean%2C%20boolean%5D%20%3D%20%5Bfalse%2C%20false%2C%20false%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.on('accelerate'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.door(0%2C%20false)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.door(1%2C%20false)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.door(2%2C%20false)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20door(index%3A%20number%2C%20state%3A%20boolean)%3A%20void%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.doorState%5Bindex%5D%20%3D%20state%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.emit('doorStateChange'%2C%20...this.doorState)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20bus%20%3D%20new%20Bus()%3B%0D%0A)):

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

type AddParameters<ListenersT, EventT> =
    ListenersT extends (...args: infer ArgsT) => void
        ? (event: EventT, ...args: ArgsT) => Promise<boolean>
        : never;

type EmitSignatures<ListenersT> =
    { [EventT in keyof ListenersT]: AddParameters<ListenersT[EventT], EventT> };
type EmitAll<ListenersT> = UnionToIntersection<EmitSignatures<ListenersT>[keyof ListenersT]>

type OnSignatures<ListenersT, ReturnT> =
    { [EventT in keyof ListenersT]: (event: EventT, listener: ListenersT[EventT]) => ReturnT };
type OnAll<ListenersT, ReturnT> =
    UnionToIntersection<OnSignatures<ListenersT, ReturnT>[keyof ListenersT]>;

type EventEmitter<ListenersT> = EmitterInterface<ListenersT>;

export interface EmitterInterface<ListenersT>
{
    emit: EmitAll<ListenersT>;
    on: OnAll<ListenersT, this>;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

interface VehicleEvents
{
    accelerate(acceleration: number): void;
    brake(deceleration: number): void;
}

interface BusEvents extends VehicleEvents
{
    doorStateChange(front: boolean, middle: boolean, rear: boolean): void
}

interface Vehicle<E extends VehicleEvents> extends EventEmitter<E>
{
    onSig: OnSignatures<E, this>;
    onSigs: OnSignatures<E, this>[keyof E];
}

class Vehicle<E extends VehicleEvents>
{
    public constructor()
    { this.on('brake', () => this.flashBrakeLights()); } // supposed to work?

    public flashBrakeLights(): void {}

    public hitTheGas(strength: number): void
    { this.emit('accelerate', strength * 42); } // supposed to work?

    public test(): void
    {
        this.onSig.accelerate;
        this.onSig.brake;
        this.onSigs('accelerate', (a) => undefined); // error I don't understand
        this.onSigs('brake', (d) => undefined); // error I don't understand
        this.onSigs('foo', () => undefined); // supposed to error
    }
}

interface Bus extends EventEmitter<BusEvents> {}

class Bus extends Vehicle<BusEvents>
{
    public doorState: [boolean, boolean, boolean] = [false, false, false];

    public constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.on('accelerate', () => {
            this.door(0, false);
            this.door(1, false);
            this.door(2, false);
        });
    }

    public door(index: number, state: boolean): void
    {
        this.doorState[index] = state;
        this.emit('doorStateChange', ...this.doorState);
    }
}

export const bus = new Bus();
```

The `E` type is declared as extension of `VehicleEvents`, which should be enough to let Typescript know there are the `accelerate` and `brake` events, shouldn't it?

Any explanations for why this doesn't work? Any ideas for how to fix this or to achieve what I need in another way?

Comment: Inside `Vehicle` the problem is that `E` is not known, so all that conditional and mapped type magic will not be fully resolvable and so you will get errors. Also `onSigs` is a union of signatures so that will not work as you expect it to even from outside  (the parameters have to be intersections of all possibilities.

Comment: Yes `E` is not known inside `Vehicle`, but it *is* known that it extends `VehicleEvents`. So I assume Typescript doesn't even resolve it as far as possible. Considering `onSigs` I thought of that as well, but shouldn't the first parameter be a union of all event names then and thus error as well (it only complains about the handler part for me)? Also, any ideas how I could achieve what I need? :(

Comment: I will think about it .. I answered a similar question a while ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369299/can-i-reuse-the-parameter-definition-of-a-function-in-typescript/50375712#50375712, but it was not extensible either .. I tried a couple of things but did't get it to work the way you want unfortunately

Comment: [sub-events](https://github.com/vitaly-t/sub-events) is a fully-extensible alternative ;) If you want details - just ask, and I will publish a detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that inside the class those fancy conditional types (not sure where they came from [cough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369299/can-i-reuse-the-parameter-definition-of-a-function-in-typescript/50375712#50375712)) can't be resolved if they still contain unresolved type parameters. So while your approach to use a generic type parameter for extensibility seems like a good idea, the effect is that it makes `on` and `emit` unusable inside the class.

One solution is not to use a type parameter, just use event interface itself. The problem with that (as you undoubtedly found) is that it makes the class impossible to extend, as any derived version of `on` and `emit` will not be compatible with the base type version.

To fix this issue we can use a function that removes `on` and `emit` from the base type. This is a bit hackish but I don't think there is a better way.

```
interface VehicleEvents {
  accelerate(acceleration: number): void;
  brake(deceleration: number): void;
}

interface BusEvents extends VehicleEvents {
  doorStateChange(front: boolean, middle: boolean, rear: boolean): void
}

interface Vehicle extends EventEmitter<VehicleEvents> {}

class Vehicle {
  public constructor() {
    this.on('brake', () => this.flashBrakeLights()); //ok 
  }

  public flashBrakeLights(): void { }

  public hitTheGas(strength: number): void { this.emit('accelerate', strength * 42); } // ok

}

type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
interface Bus extends EventEmitter<BusEvents> { }

function extendEmitter<TBaseCtor extends new (...a: any[])=> any>(ctor: TBaseCtor){
  return ctor as (new (...a: ConstructorParameters<TBaseCtor>) => Omit<InstanceType<TBaseCtor>, 'on' | 'emit'>)
}
class Bus extends extendEmitter(Vehicle) {
  public doorState: [boolean, boolean, boolean] = [false, false, false];

  public constructor() {
    super();
    this.on('accelerate', () => {
      this.door(0, false);
      this.door(1, false);
      this.door(2, false);
    });
  }

  public door(index: number, state: boolean): void {
    this.doorState[index] = state;
    this.emit('doorStateChange', ...this.doorState);
  }

}

export const bus = new Bus();
```

The above version does not ensure that the newly derived implements the base event aproriately. We can write a version that would validate that but it would require a small chaneg to the original definitions to allow us to extract the event interface from the base type:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

type AddParameters<ListenersT, EventT> =
    ListenersT extends (...args: infer ArgsT) => void
        ? (event: EventT, ...args: ArgsT) => Promise<boolean>
        : never;

type EmitSignatures<ListenersT> =
    { [EventT in keyof ListenersT]: AddParameters<ListenersT[EventT], EventT> };
type EmitAll<ListenersT> = UnionToIntersection<EmitSignatures<ListenersT>[keyof ListenersT]>

type OnSignatures<ListenersT, ReturnT> =
    { [EventT in keyof ListenersT]: (event: EventT, listener: ListenersT[EventT]) => ReturnT };
type OnAll<ListenersT, ReturnT> =
    UnionToIntersection<OnSignatures<ListenersT, ReturnT>[keyof ListenersT]>;

type EventEmitter<ListenersT> = EmitterInterface<ListenersT>;

export interface EmitterInterface<ListenersT>
{
    emit: EmitAll<ListenersT>;
    on: OnAll<ListenersT, this> & {__source: ListenersT}; // do not use __source, just here to allow EventTypes to work
}

type EventTypes<T> = T extends EventEmitter<infer U> ? U : never;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

interface VehicleEvents {
  accelerate(acceleration: number): void;
  brake(deceleration: number): void;
}

interface BusEvents extends VehicleEvents {
  doorStateChange(front: boolean, middle: boolean, rear: boolean): void
}

interface Vehicle extends EventEmitter<VehicleEvents> {}

class Vehicle {
  public constructor() {
    this.on('brake', () => this.flashBrakeLights()); //ok 
  }

  public flashBrakeLights(): void { }

  public hitTheGas(strength: number): void { this.emit('accelerate', strength * 42); } // ok

}

type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
interface Bus extends EventEmitter<BusEvents> { }


function extendEmitter<TBaseCtor extends new (...a: any[])=> any>(ctor: TBaseCtor){
  return function<TEvents extends EventTypes<InstanceType<TBaseCtor>>>(){
    return ctor as (new (...a: ConstructorParameters<TBaseCtor>) => Omit<InstanceType<TBaseCtor>, 'on' | 'emit'> & EventEmitter<TEvents>)
  }
}

class Bus extends extendEmitter(Vehicle)<BusEvents>() {
  public doorState: [boolean, boolean, boolean] = [false, false, false];

  public constructor() {
    super();
    this.on('accelerate', () => {
      this.door(0, false);
      this.door(1, false);
      this.door(2, false);
    });
  }

  public door(index: number, state: boolean): void {
    this.doorState[index] = state;
    this.emit('doorStateChange', ...this.doorState);
  }

}

export const bus = new Bus();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for finding a solution. I don't understand the second part, though. Just using the changes from the first code block works in my test. Maybe this is because our implementations differ?

Comment: @Neon perhaps, it you provide a repo with the code I can have a look. We can also chat on gitter if you need more info, this is an interesting topic :)