# How to type an extensible EventEmitter in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to implement an extensible `EventEmitter` pattern in TypeScript.

This is the way it is supposed to be used:

```js
class DataEmitter<T, _EE extends Dict<any[]>> extends EventEmitter<DefaultMerge<_EE, { data: [T] }>> {
 // ...
}
```

So any class extending `DataEmitter` might pass another object type defining new events it is capable of emitting, and so on.

This is how I tried to define it:

```js
type Listener<T extends any[]> = (...args: T) => void

type Dict<V> = {
  [name: string]: V
}

type DefaultMerge<A, B> = A & B

type EventEmitter_EE<_EE extends Dict<any[]> = {}> = DefaultMerge<
  _EE,
  {
    listen: [{ event: 'listen' | keyof _EE }]
  }
>

interface EE<_EE extends Dict<any[]> = {}> {
  addListener<K extends keyof _EE>(
    event: K,
    listener: Listener<_EE[K]>
  ): void

  emit<K extends keyof _EE>(event: K, ...args: _EE[K]): void
}

class EventEmitter<_EE extends Dict<any[]> = {}>
  implements EE<EventEmitter_EE<_EE>>
{
  private __listeners: {
    [K in keyof EventEmitter_EE<_EE>]?: Listener<EventEmitter_EE<_EE>[K]>[]
  } = {}

  addListener<K extends keyof EventEmitter_EE<_EE>>(
    event: K,
    listener: Listener<EventEmitter_EE<_EE>[K]>
  ): void {
    this.__listeners[event] = this.__listeners[event] || []
    this.__listeners[event].push(listener)

    // >> TypeScript Error << \\
    this.emit('listen', { event })
  }

  emit<K extends keyof EventEmitter_EE<_EE>>(
    event: K,
    ...args: EventEmitter_EE<_EE>[K]
  ): void {
    const listeners = [...(this.__listeners[event] || [])]

    for (const listener of listeners) {
      listener.call(this, ...args)
    }
  }
}
```

Note the `EventEmitter` class comes with a default event called `"listen"`.

However, TypeScript complains about the referred line with the following error message:

```
Argument of type '[{ event: K; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type
 '_EE["listen"] & [{ event: "listen" | keyof _EE; }]'.
  Type '[{ event: K; }]' is not assignable to type '_EE["listen"]'.
```

Ideally, it should understand that `"listen"` is a default event of `EventEmitter` and infer its type to be `"listen" | keyof _EE` as defined.

My guess is that `DefaultMerge<A, B>` is not well defined; it should return an object type that will "first look in B, then, if not defined, look at A".

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

```ts
// >> TypeScript Error << \\
this.emit('listen', { event })
```

The error in the above case is because TypeScript doesn't know what `_EE` is within the class, and considering `EventEmitter_EE` has been defined as an intersection, it tries to infer the type as:

```ts
'_EE["listen"] & [{ event: "listen" | keyof _EE; }]'
```

The same statement works in below cases, where TypeScript is able to infer `_EE`:

```ts
class SomeClass {
  someMethod() {
    const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    const event = 'listen';
    eventEmitter.addListener(event, () => console.log('eventOccured'));
    eventEmitter.emit('listen', { event });
  }
}
```

```ts
type click_EE = {
  click: [{event: 'click'}]
}
class SomeClass {
  someMethod() {
    const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter<click_EE>();
    const event = 'listen';
    eventEmitter.addListener(event, () => console.log('eventOccured'));
    eventEmitter.emit('listen', { event });
  }
}
```

You can also check [Extensible, strongly typed Event Emitter Interface in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763701/extensible-strongly-typed-event-emitter-interface-in-typescript) and see if it helps.