# TypeScript type mapping: how to wrap function return values?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types, conditional-types

i'm looking to take interfaces like this one:

```
interface Store {
  test1(): void
  test2(a: string, b: number): RegExp
  test3<T>(a: string, b: number): Promise<T>
}
```

and by using a mapped type such as
`type AsyncStore = Asyncd<Store>`
i would like to promise-wrap the function return values:

```
type AsyncStore = Asyncd<Store>
  // {
  //   test1(): Promise<void>
  //   test2(a: string, b: number): Promise<RegExp>
  //   test3<T>(a: string, b: number): Promise<T>
  // }
```

i need an improvement over this "`Asyncd`" type i've made:

```
type AnyFunc = (...args: any[]) => any

// wraps a type in a promise, unless it's already a promise
type PromiseWrap<T> = T extends Promise<any> ? T : Promise<T>

// wrap a function's return type in a promise
type PromiseWrapResult<Func extends AnyFunc> =
  ReturnType<Func> extends Promise<any>
    ? (...args: any[]) => ReturnType<Func>
    : (...args: any[]) => Promise<ReturnType<Func>>

// perform promise wrapping for each function
type Asyncd<Subject> = {
  [Prop in keyof Subject]: Subject[Prop] extends AnyFunc
    ? (...args: any[]) => PromiseWrap<ReturnType<Subject[Prop]>>
    : Subject[Prop]
}

interface MyStore {
  test1(): void
  test2(a: string, b: number): RegExp
  test3<T>(a: string, b: number): Promise<T>
}

type MyAsyncStore = Asyncd<MyStore>
  // {
  //   test1(...args: any[]): Promise<void>
  //   test2(...args: any[]): Promise<RegExp>
  //   test3(...args: any[]): Promise<{}>
  // }
```

almost there, but not quite — what's missing:

- all function arguments are lost, becoming `...args: any[]`
- generics don't survive the transformation (notice test3).. is there a way to preserve function generics through a type mapping?

**relevant reading material:**

- [**ts handbook:** advanced types - mapped types towards the bottom](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)
- [**ts 2.8 release:** conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html)

Comment: You can get a better version of promisify here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420657/how-to-remove-properties-and-promisify-method-via-mapped-type-in-typescript/49421381#49421381 But as far as I know you can't do it with generic parameter