# Exclude object keys by their value type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typing, mapped-types, conditional-types

I want to map an object type to a subtype that includes only keys whose values are of a specific type.

For example, something like `ExtractNumeric<T>`, where
`ExtractNumeric<{ str: string, num: number }>` should be equivalent to the type: `{ num: number }`

I've tried this, but it does not work:

`type ExtractNumeric<T> = { [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends number ? T[k] : never }`

This snippet throws a type error:
`let obj: ExtractNumeric<{ str: string, num: number }> = { num: 1 }`

Because although the `str` key expects a value of `never`, the compiler complains about its absence.

Comment: https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c seems that's exactly answers your question

Comment: `type ExtractNumeric<T> = Pick<T, { [k in keyof T]-?: T[k] extends number ? k : never }[keyof T]>
let obj: ExtractNumeric<{ str: string, num: number }> = { num: 1 }` Although for sure a duplicate ..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Linked [aticle](https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c) in the comment, but in a nutshell:

```
type SubType<Base, Condition> = Pick<Base, {
    [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
}[keyof Base]>;

type ExtractNumeric<T> = SubType<T, number>
```

Comment: This mostly works, but consider this:
`let obj: SubType<{ str: string, num: number }, boolean> = { num: 1, str: "" }`

It does not produce an error, but I guess that is more due to TypeScripts quirks about empty object types

Comment: As of TypeScript 4.1, there's an easier way to do this by re-mapping keys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63990350