# Dynamically modify/filter type to create a new type

Tags: typescript

Given a type such as:

```
type PromiseFunc = () => Promise<unknown>;
type A = {
  key1: string;
  key2: string;
  key3: PromiseFunc;
  key4: string;
  key5: PromiseFunc;
  key6: SomeOtherType1[];
  key7: SomeOtherType2[];
  key8: string;
  key9: PromiseFunc;
  // ...
};
```

Given a type such as the above, I would like to create a new type, `B`, such that:

- All keys in `A` that are type `string` are present as type `string` in `B`
- All keys in `A` that are type `PromiseFunc` are present as type `string` in `B`
- All keys in `A` that are an array type are excluded from `B`

Is this possible in some generic way? I have hundreds of types such as `A`, but would like to find a way to convert them into types like `B`. I do not control the generation of the `A` types.

Edit:
Link to an additional solution: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsCAFATgewLYEsDO0C8UAFAJRT4B8UqmuEAPPIhQNwBQokUA4hAHYQUWAMY1sectXTiGOYEL4BzCmzYB6NVAAq4aMDRQAZlgA2iFB12wEcSQG82UKAGsIIAIwAuKHIWL2Tq4gAEzeTMjSdI4ubgDM3nB8IADaALrRQQAs3rwCQqKReBluAKzepORUYnT0fACuGABGgioAvuyWXACycGCouBhwOpBaaADKJmh8WM70APKNAFZQEAAeiHwAJjhQAEoQwmgom-S+WEoANFCJIBRXPcDCABYAanAmdRDDEFf7OHVmN4fL66KiEBxOZIAaSg5xiIDQhmoIlm0ScC0WFzRUAhTjx0LcsL48MRUAxqW8GIJIFSK3W-G2UAezyBn2+UAA-FAoYTvAIAG6CAJ41rJIKk8nRCgUvYQf6A95s3TsdqqTjQfqDap4UYTKYzb4AYSmgpQ5noWjBTN6-Rwg2+usm01mWiu4W1Pyg9SaLSgADJrX0hHahrpHfqXVdcoIRB6oAAfHzyc6KK5nJQqNiHPhyHyYCCsiDeTVwD3h51Gk2Cc1MOBW3FBLxQADkhjQaGbWMCblCUHcXfh2RbWE2mU7bHaQA

Comment: Did you already consider using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)? A similar question was asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56431395/1263015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured out how to do this, I'm sure there is a more optimized way to combine these type conversions but this is what I have currently and it works:

```
type PromiseFunc = () => Promise<unknown>;


// A type whose keys we want to drop.
type SomeOtherType1 = {
    key1: string[];
};

// Another type whose keys we want to drop.
type SomeOtherType2 = {
    key1: number;
};
type A = {
    key1: string;
    key2: string;
    key3: PromiseFunc;
    key4: string;
    key5: PromiseFunc;
    key6: SomeOtherType1[];
    key7: SomeOtherType2[];
    key8: string;
    key9: PromiseFunc;
};

// Start by building a filter type we can call with the types we want
// and converting all other types to a standard type.
type Filter<T, ConditionOne, ConditionTwo> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends ConditionOne
        ? string
        : T[Key] extends ConditionTwo
        ? string
        : number;
};

// Do the conversion to a new type that only has string and number types.
type ConvertedType = Filter<A, string, PromiseFunc>;


// Now that we only have two types we can drop all the types that don't
// match the type we want (which is string), we'll convert all those keys
// to never which will drop them from our new type.
type PickByValueType<T, U> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends K ? (T[K] extends U ? K : never) : never]: T[K];
};

// Generate the final type that is only the keys which are strings.
type FilteredType = PickByValueType<ConvertedType, string>;
```

The main issue I was encountering was where I have `number` I originally had `never` which I thought should have automatically excluded these keys from the type but it didn't (it was only changing the type to never). Looking at [this issue on the TS issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40833) provided some insight. Apparently this is in TS 4.1.2 which is what I'm using, but I must still be doing something wrong and I'm sure this can be optimized further if the `Filter` type is combined with the `PickByValueType` type.

For anyone who may encounter this answer later the reason two type conversions have to be used here is because we have multiple types we need to account for and convert. If you want to simply include several types you can do that like this:

```
...

type GrabTypes<T, U, U2> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends K
        ? T[K] extends U
            ? K
            : T[K] extends U2
            ? K
            : never
        : never]: T[K];
};

type GrabbedTypes = GrabTypes<A, string, SomeOtherType1[]>
```

There are already several questions on SO about using `omit` to exclude certain types, but I couldn't find a lot of good examples that let you drop multiple keys with different types. I think this could somehow be extended to handle the conversion too, but I couldn't think of how to do it within the constraints of the ternary operator:

```
...

type GrabTypesAndConvertOne<T, U, TypeToConvert> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends K
        ? T[K] extends U
            ? K
            : T[K] extends TypeToConvert
            ? K // <- Here is where the type change logic would live
            : never
        : never]: T[K];
};

type GrabbedTypes = GrabTypesAndConvertOne<A, string, PromiseFunc>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had not seen that question you linked in your commend, appreciate you finding that. And yes, I've run into the same problem regarding requirement #2. I don't control type `A`, but that second requirement is critical to the work I'm trying to do unfortunately

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I've updated my answer with a working solution that meets all the criteria, take a look when you have a chance. Maybe you'll think of a way to optimize it better. If you do please tag me.

Comment: Thanks! I added a link to a typescriptlang.org playground in my question that has another solution a friend and I came up with (link is too long to put in this comment)

Comment: Thanks for the playground link. This is a good solution as well. Either one still feels pretty messy unfortunately.