# Create a derived type from class, but omit the constructor (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, derived-types

I have an interface and class defined like this:

```js
interface Foo {
  constructor: typeof Foo;
}

class Foo {
  static bar = 'bar';

  constructor(data: Partial<Foo>) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }

  someMethod() {
    return this.constructor.bar;
  }

  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
}
```

The interface is necessary so that `this.constructor` is strongly typed. However, it breaks my ability to pass a plain object into the class constructor:

```
const foo = new Foo({ prop1: 'asdf', prop2: 1234 });

// Argument of type '{ prop1: string; prop2: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Foo>'.
//  Types of property 'constructor' are incompatible.
//    Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'typeof Foo'.
//      Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature 'new (data: Partial<Foo>): Foo'.
```

I understand the error message, but I don't know a way around it. Is there any way have a `Partial<Foo>` which allows me to pass a plain object? Here's a playground:

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnILogDOYUArgmOlAFzJgCeADhOjGpgNy4C+uXAgA2cEiS5Y8BMnDDAEyAEZwoyALzIA5Cqhbe+QsTKVqtABQATOXAYAFVfLjCAPBnQA+AJQ5DBAPJKAFYQ1AB0YiTAAOYg5mAAFsAkADTI1mBwXrwEAoYk6AC2EACyEInoluY+0gTIUOUUUCCMSSRhRKTkVDRQYbo5yHkELFDoLACMDCag0YOj4wBMDCAUhUrQvHmdZMgwmBrIIBAA7pLm2MgLkwxaYpYwWmnXy8gTiwDMACxD2UA)

Comment: Not sure what's your intention, seems like you trying to access static property from instance, that's not possible, also interface is redundant, [checkout this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=55#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oQC5iwS2GgCMwAnaAXmgHITTqBuVdaYeAO21IFdgt5SACgAmuMAC5oABTL4wIADwJ4APgCUKFhgDyRAFYBTPgDpIEPAHN2grAAs8EADTRRONUwwBfZhgjwAtgYAsgZ28MKCGmgYGKSh3KTscIjGdB7Q3iwADqTwWQCMklx47BbpOXkATEVYpCVlqJlsnFjQAGaIlNDsBgDuyfCCyNAVBZLUkMJt1M6j1TT5lQDMACzUGe5AA)

Comment: Thanks Eric. You can access static properties from an instance via `this.constructor`, and it is not uncommon to do so. The redundant interface is also necessary because you cannot type the `constructor` method on a class definition. This uses "interface merging", which is a feature of TypeScript and is also not uncommon: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841#issuecomment-502845949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding what I needed in this wonderful answer:

[how to remove properties via mapped type in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397567/how-to-remove-properties-via-mapped-type-in-typescript)

The code in that answer creates a derived type containing *only* methods. I needed to do the inverse of that. The following `NonMethods<T>` helper creates a derived type with all of the methods removed.

```
type NonMethodKeys<T> = ({[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Function ? never : P })[keyof T];  
type NonMethods<T> = Pick<T, NonMethodKeys<T>>;
```

[Here's the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=49#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwLIWACzgEwNIRAZwB4AVAPigF4oAKAbwG0AFKASwSgGs84AzKYgLoAufkwFQIAD2AQEmfFABiAVwQBjYC0RQA-FAQQAbhABOUEcwC+ASnpcQvfgIDcUKAChQkWIhTosRGSUUIwsahwkADQ+yKgYOHiBpKSu7u5sMiY8AIZq0IpwcFC07m5qiPjAJsoacCYiXhCOBXDO7pZpagA22fgKLcWlUJXZmmpQAEbZZlQA5FMms21D5QiV1bUm1Jij2SLwsf7yhC2k1oNubgDyEwBWEBoAdL34LADmCNToLPjRO8DZaxtNwdIb4OAAWwgfni1HOJUuUBMqGUJnY33wj1W6xqwDqjwWwKgoLcYBMcDAAEYROs2G8iWSKQAmHQiBDKCETUxtUHY4BQHiFYIGADuSkKdCgjKpIlmvUwPFm0WlTJElKZAGYACzEoFAA)

Answer (score 5):

Here's the actual type creating a derived type from a class omitting the constructor (as in the question title) and keeping regular methods:

```js
type NonConstructorKeys<T> = ({[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends new () => any ? never : P })[keyof T];
type NonConstructor<T> = Pick<T, NonConstructorKeys<T>>;
```

Usage with the `Foo` from the question:

```js
type FooNonConstructorKeys = NonConstructorKeys<Foo>; // "prop1" | "prop2" | "someMethod"
type FooNonConstructor = NonConstructor<Foo>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to define an interface and then use it, then you have to define the properties in the interface itself and not the class.

```js
interface Foo {
  prop1: string; // define your properties here
  prop2: number;
}

class Foo {
  static bar = 'bar';

  constructor(data: Partial<Foo>) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }

  someMethod() {
    return Foo.bar; // notice how I access static variables now
  }

}

const foo = new Foo({ prop1: 'asdf', prop2: 1234 });
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIAOU6hAjAFzIDOYUoA5gNzID0ryAJhDKCgJ7oArlCIlC0MMAjVkAC2gR8Y0gCYqIIQFsARtCa4AvrlwIANnGqyMWPAVpwpCZDriiAvMgDkrqF4PKCOggtFBCCGDoUAAUnI5wVAAKblJwZgA8NgB8AJQ4ygQA8joAVhARAHSW1MAMINFgcsDUADRc8TkGBMbK1OhaEACyEI3onNF5dgTIUCMiIGiYFb4s7Mgg6E4ocugA7sgAksiISFY0YI7AzgBubsBwOmYy63vKPT1BIWDIMJjIniAIPsbNFsCpyFQvJZODAvG1iGoqGRVABmAAsyEMnSAA)

Comment: Thanks. I need `this.constructor` because this is a base class (eg. abstract) which is extended by other classes. Each extended class will define its own "bar" value.