# Typescript keyof generic AND extends a type

Tags: typescript

Given the following interface:

```js
interface Payload {
  value1: number;
  value2: string;
}
```

I want to create a function that accepts `Payload[]` and only the keys of `Payload` that extend `number`. Something like this:

```js
function F<T, K extends keyof T, T[K] extends number>(arr: T[], property: K) {
  //
}

function foo(payloads: Payload[]) {
  F(payloads, "value1"); // should work
  F(payloads, "value2"); // should not work because value2 is a string
  F(payloads, "value3"); // should not work because value3 not in Payload[]
}
```

#### [See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwJ4BsD2cAmyA3gLABQyyAbnFgK4QCMAXMiHQLYBG0A3OZRr0IAJlYBnMFFABzfmQC%205cjDogEYYDhDIAYgB4AKgBpkAaWQQAHpBD5xyANYQMOGMhMeA2mYC6lmwg7B3ZuaAA%20AAo4KChWQy9fUwAHKBxk6DAMVjMASnkVNQ0tHRgcHEjkzFwCcVZ0bDx8RNziAT1K6qbxUwAiIQZGXvzkAHpR5HEACxw6LEIAdxwoR3bdTsbavoHRYd4xienZ%20bYcMGQlleQeBDg6cRQdkWRgBzhJqVk1jZr7bdoGABmPYHSYzOaEEBnC7LRzXCC3e6PAEQQGnc6gNBdAiJcgKIA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this to work using a mapped type that only keeps `number` and `number | undefined` properties:

```js
interface Payload {
    value1: number;
    value2: string;
    value3?: number;
    value4?: string;
}

type NumberOnly<T> = {
    // Doesn't allow `number | undefined` if `strictNullChecks` is enabled
    //[key in keyof T as T[key] extends number ? key : never]: T[key];
    // This will always allow `number | undefined` on top of just `number`
    [key in keyof T as T[key] extends number | undefined ? key : never]: T[key];
};

function F<T extends NumberOnly<any>, K extends keyof NumberOnly<T>>(arr: T[], property: K) {
    const value = arr[0][property];
    return value;
}

function foo(payloads: Payload[]) {
    F(payloads, "value1"); // should work
    F(payloads, "value2"); // should not work because value2 is a string
    F(payloads, "value3"); // should work (you can filter undefined if you want)
    F(payloads, "value4"); // should not work because value4 is a string
    F(payloads, "value5"); // should not work because value5 not in Payload[]
}
```

*technically it would also accept `value5: undefined` but not e.g. `value5: string | undefined`, an edge case that shouldn't really matter.*

It only accepts `value1` and `value3`:

[image: Example result]

*based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63990350/14274597) making use of a [TypeScript 4.1 feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#key-remapping-mapped-types)*

Comment: I was also using v4.3.5 although without a `tsconfig.json`, and now that I checked, enabling `strictNullChecks` does break `number | undefined`. I'll update my answer (and the screenshot) to fix/mention this, along with fixing your issue of not being able to index.

Comment: Great! The part I couldn't crack was `T extends NumberOnly<any>`. FWIW, [here's a generic version](https://tsplay.dev/mx5B7W).