# How to get rid of those entries of an TypeScript object type where the values are `never`?

Tags: typescript

How do I have to implement a type `GetRidOfNeverValues<T>` that removes all entries of an object type (let's say: `Record<string, any>`) where the value is never?

For example

```
type A = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: never;
};

type B = GetRidOfNeverValues<A>;

/*
  type B shoud now be:

  {
    a: number;
    b: string;
  }

*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63990350/16781396) to create a helper type:

```typescript
type RemoveValues<T, U> = { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends U ? never : P]: T[P] }
```

From which we can derive `RemoveNever`:

```typescript
type RemoveNever<T> = RemoveValues<T, never>
```

Or, if you only want the `GetRidOfNeverValues` type:

```typescript
type GetRidOfNeverValues<T> = { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends never ? never : P]: T[P] } 
// same as RemoveNever
```

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgLmRAFcBbAI2h2XMIGcwpQBzahQkCANyoF8swATwAOKAEoRSAex4A1OABtiEOgB4AKgBpkAVQB8yALyZkAbQAKyUMgDWEQVJjJ1eOs4sBdZBAAekEAAmbjrIAPxE3NDIhOYehOqeyPwCIuKSMhAAcpFQGgbGEtJyispqWhE8UHpYKaLIAEJGyIUZ2ZWqqAYA9F0mBERklFAA3DT0jCyjvEA)